# LibGDX crashes when creating a button

Tags: libgdx, crash

I'm new to LibGdx. I have been programming java for a year, but today I got an error with a Button in LibGdx.

What's causing it, and how can I fix it?

```
@Override
        public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            batch.begin();
            background.draw(batch);
            batch.end();
            }
        @Override
        public void show() {
            batch = new SpriteBatch();

 //   THE ERROR IS HERE|
    //                 V
            // BUTTON
            Skin skinLibgdx = new Skin();
            TextureAtlas ta =  new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("Button.pack"));
            skinLibgdx.addRegions(ta);

            Button button = new Button(skinLibgdx);
            button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("ABC");
                }
            });

        }

        ...

    }
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle registered with name: default
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.get(Skin.java:145)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.get(Skin.java:132)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button.<init>(Button.java:50)
    at com.me.game.screen.MainMenu.show(MainMenu.java:53)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at com.me.game.screen.Splash$1.onEvent(Splash.java:64)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.callCallback(BaseTween.java:380)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.updateStep(BaseTween.java:521)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.update(BaseTween.java:424)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager.update(TweenManager.java:166)
    at com.me.game.screen.Splash.render(Splash.java:35)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.me.game.MainGame.render(MainGame.java:16)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Comment: You should post the error that you got.

Comment: @MarcoDesignerMC I think that tells you your not there any region textureAtlas the default name, to create the checks that

Comment: https://github.com/MarcoDesignerMC/Android/tree/HEAD/tParkour/core/src/com/me/game     This is the code

Comment: @MarcoDesignerMC, here is a good series describing "Styles" and setting up your skin to accommodate whichever object needs a style - [Introduction to JSON and removing code from Main Menu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkX9pcMHj4I&index=9&list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0JOwHiH1TntAdq-UDPnC2L) - in fact that [whole series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0JOwHiH1TntAdq-UDPnC2L) would be quite beneficial to get more familiar with LibGDX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The atlas alone is not enough for the button.  You would have to provide a `default` style for the button.  This either can be done directly on the skin or by a JSON file you can load. Check https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin for the details.

Check the tests of libgdx, that contain a rather complete example (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json).

e.g.

```
...
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
  default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round },
  toggle: { down: default-round-down, checked: default-round-down, up: default-round }
},
...
```

And then load it e.g.

```
Skin skinLibgdx = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"))
```

See a whole example: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/396126f3af63eb9d0d263afc59653e00e8083778/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/UITest.java